# i18n in spring-boot / thymeleaf project it's not retrieving localized messages

Tags: spring, internationalization, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying internacionalize the views of my current spring-boot / thymeleaf project. So far i did this:

- in the html files, i change the references to the texts to this:

  h2 th:text="#{about.title}"
- i add this line to my `application.properties` file:

  spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages
- put the files `*.properties` (named with the same name of the html files for the default locale and and the suffix _pt_BR for portuguese locale in the folder `/src/main/resources/templates/i18n/messages` of my project.

but when i run the project and open it in the browser, instead of being displayed the correct message, i see things like> `??about.title??`.

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try to put your properties files here /src/main/resources/i18n/messages.

Comment: @GUISSOUMAIssam I solve this issue putting all the messages in a single `message.properties` in the directory `/src/main/resources` (and removing the line `spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages` from the `application.properties`. but now I am getting a problem with localized messages like that: `logo.welcome=Welcome, <a th:href="@{/login}">log in</a> or <a th:href="@{/account}">register</a>` (with the `@{...}` variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your properties files here `/src/main/resources/i18n/messages` and not in `/src/main/resources/templates/i18n/messages`

Comment: I solve this issue putting all the messages in a single `message.properties` in the directory `/src/main/resources` (and removing the line `spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages` from the `application.properties`. but now I am getting a problem with localized messages like that: `logo.welcome=Welcome, <a th:href="@{/login}">log in</a> or <a th:href="@{/account}">register</a>` (with the `@{...}` variable).

Comment: Dont put thymleaf tags on your properties file, but a simple href if you can, something like this logo.welcome=Welcome, <a href="/login">log in</a> or <a href="/account">register</a>.

Comment: Or you can create more properties logo.welcome=Welcome, logo.login= login , logo.register= register, after that use it on your html template with th:href tags.